# How to color text in a datatable based on a vector of colors using R DT Shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am developing an R Shiny app and want to recolor squares in a datatable based on a vector of colors I provide. A simple example of what does not work is shown below. I know that you can color cells and text based on numeric values but I need to provide the exact colors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
libarry(DT)

# set the colors for each box
mycolors = c("dodgerblue2","grey","firebrick2")

# recolor entire row (works)
DT::datatable(data.frame(src=c(1,2,3),tgt=c("&#9608;"   ,"&#9608;"  ,"&#9608;")),escape=F)  %>%
formatStyle(columns = 1, color = "red") %>%
formatStyle(columns = 2, color = "blue")

# recolor based on mycolors (doesn't work)
DT::datatable(data.frame(src=c(1,2,3),tgt=c("&#9608;"   ,"&#9608;"  ,"&#9608;")),escape=F)  %>%
formatStyle(columns = 1, color = "red") %>%
formatStyle(columns = 2, color = mycolors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
dat <- data.frame(src=c(1,2,3), tgt=c("&#9608;", "&#9608;", "&#9608;"))
mycolors <- c("dodgerblue2", "grey", "firebrick2")
rgbcolors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(mycolors), 2, 
                   function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=",")))
column <- 2
jscode <- paste("function(row, data, index) {",  
                  sprintf("var colors=%s;\n$(this.api().cell(index, %s).node()).css('color', colors[index]);", 
                          sprintf("[%s]", paste(sprintf("'%s'", rgbcolors), collapse=", ")), column), "}", sep="\n")
datatable(dat, escape=FALSE, 
          options = list(rowCallback=JS(jscode))
)
```

The `rgbcolors` vector contains the RGB definitions of the colors, ready for html:

```
> rgbcolors
[1] "rgb(28,134,238)"  "rgb(190,190,190)" "rgb(238,44,44)"
```

The character string `jscode` is the Javascript code for the row callback:

```
> cat(jscode)
function(row, data, index) {
var colors=['rgb(28,134,238)', 'rgb(190,190,190)', 'rgb(238,44,44)'];
$(this.api().cell(index, 2).node()).css('color', colors[index]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: While this works perfectly, my table colors do not sort correctly (when inside my Shiny app).  Follow up question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740337/how-to-ensure-row-coloring-updates-when-r-shiny-dt-datatable-is-sorted-filtered).