# How to ensure row coloring updates when R Shiny DT datatable is sorted/filtered?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am writing an R Shiny app.  I use at DT datatable with specific colors for text entries.  When the table is resorted the colors do not stay with their correct rows.  Instead they stay in place.

I assume that I need to observe and react to the event of the table being reordered/filtered.  How do I do that?

Sample code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui= shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Test reorder DT datatave"),

 sidebarLayout(

    actionButton("button does nothing", "nothing")
 ,

 mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mydt")
 )
 )
))


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mydt <- DT::renderDataTable({

  dat <- data.frame(src=c(1,2,3), tgt=c("&#9608;", "&#9608;", "&#9608;"))

  mycolors <- c("dodgerblue2", "grey", "firebrick2")
  rgbcolors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(mycolors), 2, 
                   function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=",")))
  column <- 2
  jscode <- paste("function(row, data, index) {",  
                sprintf("var colors=%s;\n$(this.api().cell(index, 
  %s).node()).css('color', colors[index]);", 
                        sprintf("[%s]", paste(sprintf("'%s'", rgbcolors), 
  collapse=", ")), column), "}", sep="\n")
    datatable(dat, escape=FALSE, 
          options = list(rowCallback=JS(jscode))
  )
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Instead of using a callback, one could set the colors directly in the `tgt` column. Would it cause a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it OK to set the colors directly in the `tgt` column? Like this:

```
mycolors <- c("dodgerblue2", "grey", "firebrick2")
rgbcolors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(mycolors), 2, 
                   function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=",")))
tgt <- sprintf('<span style="color:%s">&#9608;</span>', rgbcolors)
dat <- data.frame(src=c(1,2,3), tgt=tgt)
datatable(dat, escape=FALSE)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!